# How to determine if a flutter application can be released closed source

Tags: flutter, dart, open-source

[Flutter](https://flutter.dev/) provides a [nice mechanism](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showLicensePage.html) to **show all license agreements** within an application, since all [packages from pub.dev](https://pub.dev) come with structured license informations.

Suppose I want to commercialize an application and I'd like to choose the **closed source** model.

**Can I somehow determine in a simple (programmatically) way, if the chosen packages allow this or require to open-source the application?**

As [jamesdlin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/179715/jamesdlin) pointed out in his comment, these licenses are [copy-left licenses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyleft). And those licenses often require derivative works to use a compatible license model as well.

Since packages recursively include other packages, things get complicated soon. I estimate my current application to show around **250 lincense files** - while I added only **14 packages**.

Moreover, some **licenses come from dart and flutter** and therefore - I suppose - allows open-source and close-source distribution.

Unfortunately, I currently see no easy way to **identify just those licenses**, which belong to added packages by me.

Comment: The types of licenses you're talking about would be "copyleft" licenses, and they are inherently viral/contagious.  That is, any package that depends on a copyleft package also would need to use a copyleft license, and so on.  In this regard, I think that you therefore need to be concerned about the licenses of only your direct dependencies.  This isn't the sort of thing that could be determined programatically short of grep'ing license text for specific terminology.

Comment: Note that what I wrote above does make an assumption that packages *correctly* follow the license terms of any packages that they depend on, which might not be true...

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no standard method exist.
Created a feature request, but the flutter teams rejected it due to out of scope.